# `Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class` messages far more verbose and common in Nougat.

Tags: android, gradle, android-library, android-7.0-nougat

Lets say I make a library with optional dependencies.

As of Android N, I am seeing *far more* `Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class` errors on anything that calls those optional dependencies.

For example, lets say there is a method in your library that makes use of RecyclerViews. However, the person using your library does not include RecyclerViews.

Even if your library contains a check to ensure that such methods will not be called if the dependency is not there, the person using the library will see this:

> I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class
>   java.lang.Class: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed
>   resolution of:
>   Landroid/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView$RecyclerListener;

Where `com.foo.bar` is the class that contains optional methods calling through to the optional dependencies.

On SDKs prior to 7, this would only be a single line message. However, in Nougat, this is a 20+ line debug log for every single method called, completely and absolutely flooding the console.

This is pretty annoying. Is there anything that can be done about this?